# Unable to reach Plex UI

Tags: curl, nginx, freebsd, plex

I have a NAS which I setup nginx as a reverse proxy to access various applications on it, including Plex. I recently upgraded `plexmediaserver` on my FreeBSD server. However, since I upgraded it, I'm unable to reach the Plex UI in a browser (http://mynas.domain.com/plex) after and I can't connect with any Plex applications on my SmartTV or XBox One. I am able to access all the other applications that are hosted on the server through the nginx reverse proxy. i.e. http://mynas.domain.com/app1 and http://mynas.domain.com/app2.

The nginx config hasn't changed:

```
location /plex {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:32400/web;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /web {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:32400;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I can verify that `plexmediaserver` is running on my server:

```
$ ps aux | grep plex
plex       656   0.0  0.6 350964  52568  -  Ss   Tue06PM     2:43.99 /usr/local/share/plexmediaserver/Plex_Media_Server (Plex Media Server)
plex       781   0.0  0.6 298028  45668  -  SN   Tue06PM     3:27.05 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.system] /usr/local/share/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-a17e99e/Framework.bundle/Contents/Resourc
plex       798   0.0  0.2 209652  14584  -  S    Tue06PM     0:50.34 /usr/local/share/plexmediaserver/Plex DLNA Server
```

If I try to curl the URL, http://mynas.domain.com/plex, on my server I get the following

```
   $ curl mynas.domain.com/plex
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to mynas.domain.com port 80: Connection refused
```

If I curl the localhost on the server with the port running Plex (`curl localhost:32400`), I get an XML output rather than HTML.

I'm not sure why I'm getting XML rather than the web UI for Plex. What would cause that to happen? Is it possible some permissions changed while I ran the update?

Comment: just in case https://nbari.com/post/plex-jail/

Comment: I'm not using jails for my apps on FreeBSD so I don't think that would apply.

Comment: What do you get on a browser at `http://mynas.domain.com:32400/`?